# Spring and FCM set different notification time for each user

Tags: spring, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have  to create a notification service in which I have send a notification to user according to its scheduled time.

Lets say One user has set a notification time of 10:00AM to 11:00AM then I have to send notification(if any) on that time only.

I am using @Scheduled annotation of spring to send notification to ALL users at fixed time. But how can I manage different scheduled time for each user ?

Please write if you need more information because I just have this scenario to explain !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the separate time for each user. Else you can set a @cron job at fixed interval let say each 5 min, and check whom to send notification in the time duration of currentTime and currentTime - 5mins. So everyone will get covered.